# How to allow "Bank Transfers"

Tags: drupal, payment-processor

I am trying to install a new payment processor.  Right now, visitors to my site only have an option to give their credit card, but I also want them to have the option to do a "Bank Account Transfer."  How would I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Unless William has addressed your "Bank Transfer" question, and you actually mean you want users to pay by entering their bank details, often known as ACH transfer.

You will need a merchant that allows that, an example post on this: https://civicrm.org/blogs/adixon/iats-next-generation-payment-processor-acheft

The link William provided indicate IATS and Vanco offer ACH,

Comment: If you are (or have) a developer or some funds, you may also be able to help extend the Stripe processor to accept ACH: https://github.com/drastik/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/issues/124

Answer (score 0):

You can find information about setting up payment processors in the documentation: [Payment Processors](http://gitbook.civicrm.org/contributions/payment-processors.html).

However, a 'bank account transfer' sounds like it would have to be a 'pay later' option. I presume that the user won't be able to do this as part of the transaction on your site but would have to separately go to their bank and make a transfer to your bank? If so, I would suggest that you enable the 'pay later' option and provide your bank details so that people can make the transfer into your account.